# Overlay a UITableView with another UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, overlay, childviewcontroller

I have a problem in the iOS application, I am currently working on:

My main goal for the moment is to present a smaller `UITableView` `overlay` over the `UITableView` `main`, when a `UIButton` in a `UITableViewCell` of `main` gets clicked. I thought this should be a good occasion to try the concept of ChildViewControllers. So I tried to using this concept, but the result isn't satisfying. There seems to be nothing. happening, but the code gets executed (I can see it in the console) and when I set a `backgroundColor`, I can see a colored square but nothing else...

I don't know whats wrong with my implementation, if you could tell me anything I am missing.

Are there better ways to achieve my goal?

```
- (void) buttonInCellOfMainTableViewPressed:(UIButton*) cartButton {
    NSLog(@"ButtonClicked");
    UIView * containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 265, 255, 247)];
//    containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
//self isn't a subclass of UITableViewController, because a ordinary 'root view' is needed... The main tableView is a subview of the root view..
    [self.view addSubview:containerView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:containerView];

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle: nil];
    OverlayController* overlayController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OverlayController"];// is a subclass of UITableViewController

    /*configure the overlayController*/

    overlayController.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
    [self addChildViewController:overlayController];
    [self.containerView addSubview:overlayController.view];
    [overlayController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

**Edit:** I fixed an error, so know the code looks like this:

```
- (void) buttonInCellOfMainTableViewPressed:(UIButton*) cartButton {
    NSLog(@"ButtonClicked");
    self.containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 265, 255, 247)]; 
//    containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.containerView];
//self isn't a subclass of UITableViewController, because a ordinary 'root view' is needed... The main tableView is a subview of the root view..
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.containerView];

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle: nil];
    OverlayController* overlayController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OverlayController"];// is a subclass of UITableViewController

    /*configure the overlayController*/

    overlayController.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
    [self addChildViewController:overlayController];
    [self.containerView addSubview:overlayController.view];
    [overlayController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

With this changes, the `overlayController` is visible, but looks very strange:
Some of the cells of the table in the `overlayController` don't have the specified size (44 points instead of 78 points) and overlap in a strange way. What could be wrong?

[image: A screenshot from the app]

[image: A screenshot from the storyboard, so you can see how the prototype cells look like...]

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what is that you are trying to accomplish exactly?

I would probably try to use a ContainerView.

According to apple:
"Container View defines a region within a view controller's view subgraph that can include a child view controller. Create an embed segue from the container view to the child view controller in the storyboard"

I had use this approach before to have two tableviews in the same view.. One on the top part of the screen and the other on the bottom.

I don't know if you are trying to accomplish something different. But I would check the container view approach.

Comment: The problem with using a container view in the storyboard is that the embedded view controller is instantiated at the same time as its parent controller, so it will appear immediately. The OP wants to be able to add the child controller after a user interaction.

Comment: But you can make the container view hidden just like any other view, then show it when it's time to display the top table view. Should work fine.

Comment: I tried it using a ContainerView in storyboard, but the cells looked as strange as they do now, so I tried to do everything in code.

Comment: That is because you Need to add a background to your container view ... Otherwise it will be transparent or clear.. Also make sure you are not doing anything funky in your code like adding the sub views twice.

Comment: @KikoLobo I don't get what you want to say... Can you explain a little bit more, please? Did you see the screenshots I added?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that self.containerView is nil, so its bounds will be CGRectZero. You need to change that second line in your method to,

```
self.containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 265, 255, 247)];
```

Comment: Thanks... I changed the code and the question, because there is still a strange problem..

Comment: @RobindeBois, is your main table in a UITableViewController or a UIViewController? If the former, then you probably shouldn't do this. The view of a UITableViewController is the table view, so anything you make a subview will be a subview of the table which is not a good thing. If you use a UIView controller, then you can add the child controller's view to self.view (which is not  the table view).